# How can I Insert and retrieve a JSON format object into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, object

This is the problem. I am looking to store an object with a nested array into a SQL column in my database. My goal is to store the whole object and retrieve it when necessary. There is no need to access individual items inside the JSON object.

Right now what I am doing is stringifying the array to send it into the database, storing it as a string and then when retrieving the information I am decoding it with `JSON_decode($string, true)` but the JSON_decode gives me a big string inside an array and I can't do anything with it

This is how my array looks like

```
var profileData = {
profileIndex:[0],
myProfile:
    [
        [[[ 'First Name:','']],[['Last Name:','']],[[ 'Title:','']],[['Company','']],[['Cell:',''] .... 
    ]
```

(it keeps going with more values but you get the idea)

This is what it gives back after decoding the string from the server

```
["[[[\"First Name\",\"Random name\"]],[[\"Last Name\",\"Some Value\"]],[[\"Job Title\",\"Random job title\"]],[[\"Company\",\"Random company\"]] ... "]
```

Is there any way to directly store it into MySQL as JSON object? or what should I do to accomplish what I am trying to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSON is *text*. How can you store *text* in MySQL? How do you convert JSON *text* to an object graph (and vice-versa)? It looks like there was one too-many encodes or not-enough-decodes..

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Recent versions have a JSON specific dataype

Comment: Also MySQL 8 has a *native" JSON type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html which might be worth exploring vs. a varchar type.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried using the JSON type but it was not taking it as a valid datatype. I figured out the problem by using JSON.parse() and it gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @Farynx JSON since mysql 5.7, however you nee a recent PDO driver (it is the one barfing on data type 245).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MySQL varchar field is large enough to store your largest expected result.

```
// encode your JSON as a string
$asJSON = json_encode($myJSON) ;
```

Then store `$asJSON` into the varchar field in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by parsing the array given. Just used JSON.parse($myvalue) and it gave me the JSON object that was expecting